# Minim fatal exception

Tags: android, exception, processing, minim

I'm running Processing 2.02 in Windows 8, have jre 7 installed, running an emulator created for API level 11, using the latest Minim version (as of 9/20/2013).
I wrote a test sketch to make sure I can run things to the emulator (a canvas 100x100 green with a simple line drawn).  This works.
I then wrote a sketch to test out Minim playing a mp3 sound snippet.  The mp3 file is about 201K and is in the data folder
The sketch works in java but fails when I switched to Android mode.

Can someone please help guide me to get it running.  Thank you in advance.

Below is the sketch and the error I received.

***Processing sketch:
>

> ```
>   // libraries
>   import dff.minim.*;
>
>   // audio variables
>   Minim myMinim;>
>   AudioSnippet textReading;
>
>   void setup() {
>       size(100, 100);
>       background(0, 255, 0); // green background color
>       myMinim = new Minim(this);
>       textReading = myMinim.loadSnippet("testmp3.mp3");
>   }// setup
>
>   void draw() {
>   }// draw
>
>   void mouseReleased() {
>       textReading.play();
>   }// mouseReleased
>
>   void stop() {
>       myMinim.stop();
>       super.stop();
>   )// stop
> ```

***Error:

```
-post-build:

debug:
FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at processing.test.minimtest.MinimTest.setup(MinimTest.java:31)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat$Type
    at ddf.minim.Minim.<clinit>(Minim.java:65)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Minim uses javax.sound.* which is not present on Android.

Try [APWidgets](https://code.google.com/p/apwidgets/) and start with the media player examples.

The other alternative is to use the Android SDK's [Media Player](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: Hi everyone, turns out, my problem isn't the Fatal Exception with Minim.  It is with the way Processing expects files versus Android.  Processing expects to find "things" under the data folder while Android needs them under Assets folder or res folder.  So as good as Processing is as a development environment (which I love), I need to isolate the I/O (video, image, audio) files to know if I'm running in Android or not!!!

I'm open to suggestions if someone has a way to help migrate code seamlessly between Processing and Android.